# How to get the all expression required for initial condition in data flow analysis

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

How to determine all the available expression in a program before starting the available expression analysis. Because they are required for initial values.

My main confusion is that if an expression is coming more than once like a*b is coming 2 times are they two different expression or same

Comment: Use [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form); then textually equivalent expressions always have the same value because SSA values never change value.

Comment: Now I know it depends upon the domian whatever one take.....